# OpenShift Payara Memory - Cannot access Admin

Tags: java, out-of-memory, openshift, payara

We have OpenShift with images using Payara. We are very new to this, one issue we ran into was being unable to access the Payara admin console with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Is there a way to increase the memory without having to rebuild a new image?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running a JVM, I would strongly recommend starting with troubleshooting from what's documented [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/application_memory_sizing.html)

You can also dynamically adjust the memory in dynamically in your pod like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: fedora:latest
    command:
    - sleep
    - "3600"
    env:
    - name: MEMORY_REQUEST
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: test
          resource: requests.memory
    - name: MEMORY_LIMIT
      valueFrom:
        resourceFieldRef:
          containerName: test
          resource: limits.memory
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 384Mi
      limits:
        memory: 512Mi
```

Answer (score 0):

With the official Payara Server docker image, it's not possible to specify JVM memory limits without modifying the image.

However, you can modify the stock image once to take advantage of environment variable references in JVM options and then reuse the same image with different values for the environment variable. See the documentation here: https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/var-substitution/usage-of-variables.html

So you can modify the image to remove the default `-Xmx2g` JVM option with the `delete-jvm-options` asadmin command and add a new option like `${ENV=PAYARA_XMX}` with `create-jvm-options` and then start the docker container with the `PAYARA_XMX` environment variable set to e.g. `-Xmx500m`.

You can also raise an issue to request adding support for this into the stock Payara Docker image at https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/issues.